# Code to Replace Images on Click in Order?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes a look at my question :)

I am rather new-ish to web design, and totally a novice when it comes to any kind of coding. So any help at all would be appreciated!

I am making a website for a webcomic. The page is set up like this:

```
{top nav}
{comic page}
{Page navigation}
{Update blog}
```

In {Page navigation} I have these icons coded:

```
<< (first page) | < (previous page) | Page # | > (next page) | >> (newest page)
```

I would like to code the {comic page} image to switch pages on click. However, I would also like the {Page navigation} links to go to the correct pages.

I'm wondering if there is a Javascript code, or even another method, that will switch the pages automatically, so that I don't have to create a new html page for every page of the comic (there are going to be around 150). Could I create a template file, and then use javascript to replace the images?

I am also going to have an Archive page, which will list out the pages in order. Is there a way to code this to update automatically also?

I have wondered if using php would work, but I have no idea where to start with that. My webhost is currently GoDaddy, and it does give me a few databases, but I am lost on how to get all the dots connected!

Here is the code for the comic page and navigation currently:

```css
@charset "utf-8"; /* CSS Document */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
.top_nav {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 text-align:center;
}

.page {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:48%;
 max-width: 900px;
 min-width: 300px;
 margin-top: 3%;
 margin-bottom: 1.5%;
 height: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}
.comic_nav {
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 background-color: black;
 text-align:center;
}
body {
 background-color:#3A3A3A;
 color: #505050;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 1.5;
}
h2 {
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
 padding: 5px 7px;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none; 
 display: inline-block;
}

/* ============================================================
  LISTS
============================================================ */
nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
nav li {
 display: inline-block;
}
li a:link, a:visited {
 padding: 5px 7px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}
li a:hover, a:active {
 background-color:#CCC;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}
a:hover {
 color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <!-- TOP NAVIGATION -->
  <div class="top_nav">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="miragecomic.html">Home</a> |</li>
        <li> <a href="#">Archive</a> |</li>
        <li> <a href="#">About</a> |</li>
        <li> <a href="#">Cast</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION --> 
  <!-- COMIC PAGE -->
  <div class="page"> <a href="miragecomic.html"><img src="img/pages/1.jpg" style="width:100%; max-width: 900px; min-width: 400px; height:auto;" alt="Page 1" /></a> </div>
  <!-- END COMIC PAGE--> 
  <!-- COMIC NAVIGATION -->
  <div class="comic_nav">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><<</a> |</li>
        <li> <a href="#"><</a> |</li>
        <li>
          <h2>Page#</h2>
          |</li>
        <li> <a href="#">></a></li>
        |
        <li> <a href="#">>></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- END COMIC NAVIGATION -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend is a API-like server ([express, for example](http://expressjs.com/)) which would send you data (in JSON format ?) and that you could parse with JQuery.
Then, JQuery could put data in the adequate div.
Let's imagine your server has a `/comic/:id` route. If you click on `<li><a href="/comic/2">></a></li>` (because you are on the first page), it would send you :

> {
>    current: '2',
>    image: 'new-url.jpg'
>   }

Then, with jQuery : `$('.page img').src = data.image` and `$('#previousImage').href = data.current - 1` and `$('#nextImage').href = data.current + 1`, etc.

Keep in mind that's just an idea of what I think is easy to do and efficient :)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nextImage').click(function (event) {
    $.get('https://my-server.com/api' + event.target.href, function (data) {
      $('#previousImage').href = data.current - 1;
      $('#nextImage').href = data.current + 1;
      $('#currentImage').src = data.image;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8"; /* CSS Document */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
.top_nav {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 background-color: black;
 text-align:center;
}

.page {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:48%;
 max-width: 900px;
 min-width: 300px;
 margin-top: 3%;
 margin-bottom: 1.5%;
 height: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}
.comic_nav {
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 background-color: black;
 text-align:center;
}
body {
 background-color:#3A3A3A;
 color: #505050;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 1.5;
}
h2 {
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
 padding: 5px 7px;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none; 
 display: inline-block;
}

/* ============================================================
  LISTS
============================================================ */
nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
nav li {
 display: inline-block;
}
li a:link, a:visited {
 padding: 5px 7px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}
li a:hover, a:active {
 background-color:#CCC;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
}
a:hover {
 color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <!-- TOP NAVIGATION -->
  <div class="top_nav">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="miragecomic.html">Home</a> |</li>
        <li> <a href="#">Archive</a> |</li>
        <li> <a href="#">About</a> |</li>
        <li> <a href="#">Cast</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION --> 
  <!-- COMIC PAGE -->
  <div class="page"> <a href="miragecomic.html"><img id="currentImage" src="img/pages/1.jpg" style="width:100%; max-width: 900px; min-width: 400px; height:auto;" alt="Page 1" /></a> </div>
  <!-- END COMIC PAGE--> 
  <!-- COMIC NAVIGATION -->
  <div class="comic_nav">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a id="firstImage" href="/comic/first"><<</a> |</li>
        <li> <a id="previousImage" href="/comic/13"><</a> |</li>
        <li>
          <h2>Page 14</h2>
          |</li>
        <li> <a id="nextImage" href="/comic/15">></a></li>
        |
        <li> <a id="lastImage" href="/comic/last">>></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <!-- END COMIC NAVIGATION -->
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This looks very clean, and like it will work for me! I've never done anything too deep with API or servers, so I looked into Express and Node. I'm able to add Node to my GoDaddy shared server at $5 a month it seems! Would you happen to have any links to tutorials on how to set up Node and Express on a GoDaddy server? Sad to admit I'm a total newb with all of this!

Comment: Well, I don't know what's included in GoDaddy plans, but if you can access a command-line tool, just install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), then follow the [quickstart guide for express](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) :)
Alternatively, if your plan doesn't allow you to install third-party software, you can achieve the same result with a PHP API. In this case, take a look at [Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com/), it's a very lightweight PHP framework, perfect for a quick API development.

Comment: This sounds really like it'll help me out! GoDaddy permits the PHP elements. Awesome, thank you so much for all the advice! :D